# How is $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$ used to compute $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin 2x}{x}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I know that I can substitute $2x$ for $x$ in

$$\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$$

to obtain the following equality:

$$\displaystyle\lim_{2x \to 0} \frac{\sin 2x}{2x} = 1$$

But the slide below seems to suggest that

$$\displaystyle\lim_{2x \to 0} \frac{\sin 2x}{2x} = 1 \Longleftrightarrow  \displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin 2x}{2x} = 1 \tag{1}$$

(note that $2x \to 0$ becomes $x \to 0$).

What's the justification for this?

Furthermore, what's the justification for

$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \left( 2 \frac{\sin(2x)}{2x}\right) = 2 \cdot \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(2x)}{2x} \tag{2}$$ ?

[image]

Comment: Sorry for using `\displaystyle` in the original title, didn't know it caused issues...

Comment: If you know the mclaurin expansion for sin x , sin(nx) could be replaced by nx just taking the first term of the expansion (just taking the first term is accurate enough)      So limit x going to 0 sin(x)/x  could be said to be x/x which is just 1. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, what $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1$ says is that the ratio of the sine of a value to its own value approaches $1$, as the value approaches $0$.

So, if you look at $\lim_\limits{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(2x)}{2x}$, you can clearly see that as $x$ tends to $0$, the product of any factor ($2$ in this case) and $x$ must also tend to $0$. So this limit *also* involves the ratio of the sine of a value to its own value, as the value approaches $0$. Hence, this limit is equivalent to $\lim\limits_{2x \to 0} \frac{\sin(2x)}{2x}$, which in turn is equivalent to $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$.

For your second question, $2$ is a constant factor that is independent of the limit (since it is independent of $x$). Hence, pulling it out the limit is justified.

Comment: I would also add for $(2)$ (as I've found out in the meantime) that it follows follows from the limit law of multiplication. We can split the left part up into the product of two limits, and since the limit of a constant function is the constant, we end up with the constant multiplied by the limit, or the right part.

Comment: That could be regarded as a special case of a limit of products, but I would like to point out that a product of limits is only equal to a limit of products if both limits are finite.

Answer (score 5):

As $2x\to0$, $x\to0$ as well. This is because of what the "limit" really means -- it asks you to evaluate the expression as $2x$ gets smaller and smaller. But if you think about it, this is really the same thing as $x$ getting smaller and smaller. Thus the two expressions will be the same.

Pedantic note, obviously you also want to make sure it's true if $x\to0^-$ as well.

Comment: Would it be correct to say that $2x \to y$ is equivalent to $x \to \frac{y}{2}$?

Comment: @Calculemus Yes, that is a valid statement.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is to expand $\sin (2x)$ as $ 2 \sin (x) \cos(x)$.

The limit then becomes:

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{2 \sin (x) \cos(x)}{x}$$
$$=2$$